# Proper XML multicall

Tags: xml, xml-rpc

i want to send a multicall to Rtorrent Rpc instead of some singlecalls, therefor i need to know how to format my xml call.
At the moment my test xml call looks like that:

```
("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><methodCall><methodName>system.multicall</methodName>
    <params><param><value><array><data><value><struct><member><methodName>d.get_name</methodName>
        <params><param><value><string>1A0AF8BB650FEFB64A6F5A800CD2770BD1658D52</string></value></param></params></member></struct></value>
    <value><struct><member><methodName>d.get_bytes_done</methodName>
        <params><param><value><string>1A0AF8BB650FEFB64A6F5A800CD2770BD1658D52</string></value></param></params></member></struct></value>
</param></params></methodCall>");
```

But i only get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
<fault>
<value><struct>
<member><name>faultCode</name>
<value><i4>-503</i4></value></member>
<member><name>faultString</name>
<value><string>Call XML not a proper XML-RPC call.  Call is not valid XML.  Invalid XML "content".  Problem with token at '&lt;/param&gt;&lt;/params&gt;&lt;/methodCall&gt;...': mismatched tag</string></value></member>
</struct></value>
</fault>
</methodResponse>
```

For example a working single call looks like that:

```
    <?xml version=\"1.0\"?><methodCall><methodName>d.get_name</methodName>
<params><param><value><string>1A0AF8BB650FEFB64A6F5A800CD2770BD1658D52</string></value></param></params></methodCall>
```

the only info i found were these:

```
system.multicall takes one argument as an array. The array contains one
or more structs with the keys methodName and params. You can add any
number of commands.
```

Anyone an idea what i`m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version=\"1.0\"?><methodCall><methodName>system.multicall</methodName>

    <params><param><value><array><data><value><struct><member><name>methodName</name><value>

<string>d.get_name</string></value></member><member><name>params</name><value><array><data><value>

<string>7CF948608C380BA6F98527A09DD441E4D3E02702</string></value></data></array></value></member>

</struct></value><value><struct><member><name>methodName</name><value><string>d.get_name</string>

</value></member><member><name>params</name><value><array><data><value>

<string>7CF948608C380BA6F98527A09DD441E4D3E02702</string></value></data></array></value></member>

</struct></value></data></array></value></param></params></methodCall>
```